# Who survived the skirmish at the Sarlacc pit and the destruction of the Khetanna?

Tags: star-wars, return-of-the-jedi, the-mandalorian

In *Episode VI: The Return of the Jedi*, we see our heroes escape "a new definition of pain and suffering, [being] digested over a thousand years" inside a sarlacc, and in general from imprisonment by Jabba the Hutt. They sail away on a desert skiff, with the *Khetanna*, Jabba's sail barge, exploding in the background.

In the series *The Mandalorian*, we learn that

> Boba Fett and Bib Fortuna

survived.

Were there any other survivors? (Besides our heroes, of course).

Comment: I think to remember another human bounty hunter named *Dengar* who actually saved Boba Fett from the sarlaccs maw. Though i'm not entirely sure if he was onboard the Khetanna from the beginning of the mission I will try to find a proper source.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## In canon

Besides the Rebels and the characters mentioned in the question,

> Boba Fett and Bib Fortuna, whose methods of escape haven't been shown in canon yet:

According to the *[Star Wars Character Encyclopedia, New Edition](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Character_Encyclopedia,_New_Edition)*, the members of the Max Rebo Band—[**Max Rebo**](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Max_Rebo), [**Sy Snootles**](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Sy_Snootles), and [**Droopy McCool**](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Droopy_McCool)—are known to have been on the sail barge and survived, breaking up after Jabba's death:

> After Jabba's death, the band breaks up.
>
> [...]
>
> Max Rebo's band accompanies Jabba's entourage on the Hutt's Sail Barge.

—[page 134, Max Rebo](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Star_Wars_Character_Encyclopedia_New_Edi/cOueDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=max%20rebo)

In *[The Legends of Luke Skywalker](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/The_Legends_of_Luke_Skywalker)*, a mole-flea named **[Lugubrious Mote](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Lugubrious_Mote)** claims to have been present as well, surviving by riding on Luke's head:

[image: Image of Lugubrious Mote, from The Legends of Luke Skywalker: The Manga]

Her story in the collection is fairly outlandish and is likely intended to be a tall tale, but, notably, includes many details of the battle that would have been hard to learn in-universe without being there.

The only other character known to be present at the destruction of the *Khetanna* who isn't known to have been killed, or eaten by the Sarlacc, was **[Saelt-Marae](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Saelt-Marae)**, one of Jabba's goons, popularly known as "Yak Face" out-of-universe.

[image: Production photo of Saelt-Marae from Return of the Jedi]

However, he hasn't appeared in any sources since, so it's entirely possible that he was killed as well.

## In Legends

Several of the same and other characters are known to have survived in Legends, besides the Rebels:

- [Saelt-Marae](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Saelt-Marae/Legends): faked his death, went into hiding
- [Hermi Odle](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Hermi_Odle/Legends): escaped the explosion, stole one of Jabba's ships
- [Tessek](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Tessek/Legends): escaped on a speeder bike, got turned into a B'omarr monk
- [Bib Fortuna](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Bib_Fortuna/Legends): escaped on a skiff, got turned into a B'omarr monk
- [The Max Rebo Band](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Max_Rebo_Band/Legends): jumped off of the barge, went their separate ways
- [Boba Fett](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Boba_Fett/Legends): fell into Sarlacc pit, escaped, nursed back to health by Dengar

Comment: Why are Boba and Bib listed as Legends, when as the OP states, they are alive in canon.

Comment: @Skooba Legends doesn't include the events of The Mandalorian, and neither character is shown to survive in the film, so I thought it was worth mentioning.

Comment: But you have two categories listed "canon" and "legends" if they are worth mentioning as part of a complete answer, surely they belong in the "canon" category, not legends?

Comment: @Skooba The Legends section specifically describes what happens to them in Legends. The OP describes what happens to them in canon, which is a different series of events. I've updated my answer to avoid confusion.